# split listview text append to textboxes jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile

please help, I am stuck with splitting listview text at "&". I want to pass splitted text each to different inputbox.

```js
  $('#art1popsel ul').children('li').on('click',  function () {
      event.preventDefault();
      var selected = $('#art1popsel ul').text();
      var substr = selected.split('&');
      var artikl = substr[0];
      var cijena = substr[1];
      $("#art1").val($('artikl').text());
      $("#cij1").val($('cijena').text());
  });
```

It is a listview value: `<li><a href="#R1">122331 SOMETHING&42,00</a></li>`

Where did I go wrong? Tnx in advance.

Comment: please provide a **small** example using http://jsfiddle.net and update your question...

Comment: Taifun,tnx,I sent you the solution.Will make a sample on jsfiddle in case someone will need similar

Comment: And here it is:<script type="text/javascript">
$('#art1popsel ul').children('li').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
      $('#art1').val($('span.title',this).text());
      $('#cij1').val($('span.cost em',this).text());     
});      
</script> This will split listview clicked text at position & which can then be passed to whatever places You will need.I am filling to inputboxes,each with its own value.

Comment: why use listview instead selector in jquery mobile,it is easily filtered with large lists